# SQL Server CTE Hierarchy query aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to calculate `SUM` of all children with CTE here is DDL/DML. 0 values are which I don't know and to be calculated through aggregation

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Hierarchy] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [INT] NULL,
    [SalesAmount] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Product] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ID], [Hierarchy], [ParentID], [SalesAmount]) 
VALUES (1, N'root', NULL, 0),
       (2, N'T1', 1, 0),
       (3, N'T2', 1, 0),
       (4, N'C1', 2, 0),
       (5, N'C2', 3, 0),
       (6, N'C3', 2, 0), 
       (7, N'P1', 4, 1000),
       (8, N'P2', 5, 2000),
       (9, N'P3', 6, 3000)
```

I tried below query and it gives me following output,

```
WITH CT AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Hierarchy, ParentID, 0 AS Level, 
        CAST ([Hierarchy] AS VARCHAR (MAX)) AS [Linkeage]
    FROM
        dbo.Product
    WHERE 
        ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        pc.ID, pc.Hierarchy, pc.ParentID, p1.Level + 1, 
        p1.Linkeage + ' -> ' + CAST ([pc].[Hierarchy] AS VARCHAR (MAX))
    FROM 
        dbo.Product AS pc
    JOIN 
        CT AS p1 ON p1.ID = pc.ParentID
),
Aggr AS 
(
    SELECT
        TC.ParentID,
        SUM(T.SalesAmount) AS sum_TotalAmt
    FROM
        CT TC
    INNER JOIN
        Product AS T ON TC.ID = T.ID
    GROUP BY
        TC.ParentID
)
SELECT 
    ID, Hierarchy, T.ParentID, Level, Linkeage, A.sum_TotalAmt
FROM 
    CT AS T
LEFT JOIN
    Aggr AS A ON ISNULL(T.Id, T.ParentID) = A.ParentID
```

[image]

I need existing output + underlined rows as well.

Comment: What's wrong with the 0s? Afterall the sum of sales in these branches seems indeed 0 to me.

Comment: I need sum of child which needs to calculate from hierarchical query. not 0

Comment: I mean root is 0 and T1 and T2 are 0 and 0 + 0 = 0 as in root + T1 or root + T2. Still don't get what's wrong about that?

Comment: i want them to be calculated on the fly based on T1 = C1(p1) +C3 (p3) based on its childs

Comment: So root, P1, P2 and P3 are also wrong? They should be 6000, 1000, 2000, 3000 respectively?

Comment: Yes that what i need to calculate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by my-self by in different approach, i wanted to get aggregates of multiple group by values,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductType] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProductCategory] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SalesAmount] [decimal]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So i can simply get output with below

```
select [ProductType], [ProductCategory], SUM( [SalesAmount] ) as TotalSales
from Product
GROUP BY ROLLUP (ProductType,ProductCategory)
```

[image]